# Rotating a polygon around its center

Tags: c++, rotation

I have defined a polygon for a pointer:

```
    0,-12,10,12,-10,12
```

The centroid for this polygon is:

```
    0,0
```

I want to rotate the polygon around the centroid, so that 45 degrees cause the pointer to point to 2 o'clock and 180 would cause it to pointer to 6 o'clock, 270 to 9 o'clock.

I'm writing this in Qt5.6, so far my code looks like this, I know it isn't correct:

```
    QStringList lstPoints = strPoints.split(clsXMLnode::mcucPointsDelimiter);
    int intPoints = lstPoints.length();
    if ( intPoints >= 2 ) {
        int intArraySize = intPoints / 2;
        QPoint aryPts[intArraySize], ptXY = pobjChild->ptGetXY();
        int i, p;
        i = p = 0;

        while( p<intPoints ) {
            float fltX = lstPoints[p++].toFloat()
                 ,fltY = lstPoints[p++].toFloat();
            if ( fltAngle != 0.0f ) {
                double dblRadians = (fltAngle / 180.0) * M_PI
                      ,dblCosAngle = cos(dblRadians)
                      ,dblSinAngle = sin(dblRadians);
                fltX = fltX * dblCosAngle - fltY * dblSinAngle;
                fltY = fltY * dblSinAngle + fltX * dblCosAngle;
            }
    //Translate local co-ordinates to co-ordinates to be used on display
            fltX += (float)ptXY.x();
            fltY += (float)ptXY.y();
            aryPts[i++] = QPoint((int)fltX, (int)fltY);
        }
        if ( strColor.isEmpty() != true ) {
            pobjPainter->setPen(QColor(strColor));
        }
        if ( strFill.isEmpty() != true ) {
            pobjPainter->setBrush(QBrush(QColor(strFill)));
        }
        pobjPainter->drawPolygon(aryPts, intArraySize, Qt::WindingFill);
```

strPoints is a string that contains the polygon delimited by ','.

Without rotation (0) the polygon appears exactly where I would expect, but with any rotation it still appears where I expect, but doesn't look correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
    fltX *= dblCosAngle - fltY * dblSinAngle;
    fltY *= dblSinAngle + fltX * dblCosAngle;
```

this is equivalent to

```
    fltX = fltX*(dblCosAngle - fltY * dblSinAngle);
    fltY = fltY*(dblSinAngle + fltX * dblCosAngle);
```

but you should use

```
    double tmpX = fltX;
    fltX = fltX*dblCosAngle - fltY*dblSinAngle;
    fltY = fltY*dblCosAngle + tmpX*dblSinAngle;
```

Comment: Thank you, I spotted that which is why you will notice my code now reads differently, but it is still not correct.

Comment: There's also a problem with overwriting `fltX`, I just added that now.

Comment: Thank you, will try now.

Comment: Great thank you, when testing with an Angle of 45 degrees, it works perfectly, 90 however doesn't.

Comment: Oh yes, I think cos and sin are swapped in the last line.